# page layout is not showing proper result

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple template for my web site. But it is not showing proper output.

I want header,menubar,body(left nav,content,right nav),footer.

for that i am using following code but this is not showing desired output.

```
#left-side {
    position: relative;
    width:150px;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: #FF6666;
}
#right-side {
    width:150px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #00FF66;
    float: right;
}
#container{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 0 0 150px; 
    padding: 0;

}
#header {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color:#9eb9c2 ;
}
#menu-bar{
    width:100%;
    height: 20px;
    color :red;
}
#middle{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #555555;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

in html

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="menu-bar">
        </div>          

        <div id="middle">    
            <div id="left-side">
                <h3>side1</h3>    
                <ul>    
                    <li>Let me say hello</li>    
                </ul>    
            </div>

            <div id="middle-content">    
                <h2>main content</h2>    
               <p>Hwllo</p>    
            </div>

            <div id="right-side">    
                <h3>side2</h3>    
                <ul>    
                    <li>Hiii</li>    
                </ul>    
            </div>    
        </div>

        <div id="footer">    
            <h3>footer</h3>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Plase see how to get a proper layout.

Comment: And what is a "proper layout"?

Comment: left middle and right column in same row. no space between middle content and footer. Container should be centred

Comment: I want like a standard website lay out with header,menu bar,footer and middel container(left,middle and right column)

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps. Please check the Fiddle I just created. Is this what you are thinking?

You might have to look once on following concept in css - 
[Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

[Fiddle: Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TmmdE/)

```
position: inherit;
```

and

```
float: left;
```

Comment: Really I have studied but it is very confusing concept

Comment: #right-side is not ending at bottom. it it only up to showing content

Comment: How to make container centre align

Comment: Can you list out all your requirements. Make a snapshot how you are visualizing your website? Show your efforts (update the same fiddle if you want) and mention your roadblocks. - ajc